# Is a Phenom 300 single pilot able to fly non-commercially in Europe?

Tags: easa-regulations, embraer-phenom

Can a personally owned Phenom 300 be flown non-commercially by a SP typed pilot in Europe?

Comment: What would make you question that it could?

Comment: Would the "authorities" in Europe deny my flight as the only pilot onboard?

Comment: I know you're asking about regulations, but insurance companies are often much stricter and that's always worth checking out too. Even if you're type certified and meet all the legal requirements, your insurer might want a minimum number of hours in type before covering you as a single pilot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [EASA type certificate](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/EASA-TCDS-A.158_%28IM%29_EMB505-04-30042013.pdf) says yes granted the cockpit is approved and the required additional equipment is met (refer to EASA AFM).

> Minimum Flight Crew:
>
> One pilot (in the left pilot seat) plus additional
> equipment as specified in the Limitations Section of the
> EASA Approved Airplane Flight Manual

The related note:

> Approval for operation with a minimum crew of one pilot (in the left pilot seat) is
> based upon the cockpit equipment installation and arrangement evaluated during ANAC
> certification testing. No significant changes may be made to the installed cockpit equipment or
> arrangement (EFIS, autopilot, avionics, etc.), except as permitted by the approved MMEL,
> without prior approval from the responsible Aircraft Certification Office.

Comment: I have read accounts of aircraft being grounded, in France, because they only had one rated pilot in the aircraft. How do those 'stories' reconcile with the answer given?

Comment: @ymb1Sorry, I forgot to address my comment.

Comment: @MikeBrass - that would be the additional equipment not being met.